# gcc "overflow in expression" while equivalent equivalent expression works fine

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
static const unsigned long long int xx = (36 * 36 * 36 * 36) * (36 * 36 * 36 * 36);
static const unsigned long long int y = 36 * 36 * 36 * 36;
static const unsigned long long int yy = y * y;

int main()
{
  std::cout << xx << std::endl;
  std::cout << yy << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This the compilation output

```
# g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
test.cpp:2:62: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
 static const unsigned long long int xx = (36 * 36 * 36 * 36) * (36 * 36 * 36 * 36);
```

This is the execution output

```
# ./test
18446744073025945600
2821109907456
```

Can you explain why do I see this warning and different results? if 36 can fit into char then 36^8 can fit in unsigned long long int so I'm not sure what is problem here, please advise. (I'm using gcc 4.9.2)

Comment: This seems to be a very common misconception: That a later intent somehow influences the meaning of earlier code. (Where "earlier" and "later" refer to the subexpression inclusion ordering.) This is generally not the case in C++; the closest you get to some effect like that is overload resolution on operands of address-of inside a cast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
static const unsigned long long int xx = (36 * 36 * 36 * 36) * (36 * 36 * 36 * 36);
```

`36` has type `int`

∴ `36 * 36` has type `int`

∴ `(36 * 36 * 36 * 36)` has type `int`

∴ `(36 * 36 * 36 * 36) * (36 * 36 * 36 * 36)` has type `int` and overflows, which is actually undefined behavior for signed types.

You probably wanted

```
static const unsigned long long int xx = (36ull * 36 * 36 * 36) * (36 * 36 * 36 * 36);
```

As for the second case:

```
static const unsigned long long int yy = y * y;
```

`y` has type `unsigned long long`

∴ `y * y` has type `unsigned long long` so there's no overflow.

Comment: Typo - undefined behavior for unsigned types - you meant signed, right?